# How to make a button trigger image opacity change?

Tags: javascript, css, image, html, opacity

Clicking on a button should trigger the image to show up....

*EDIT* I actually got it to work, but when changing some of the ID links it stopped working and if I leave any of these functions on my sidemenus won't show up?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>MAKE A CUPCAKE! | YourCupcake.com</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Blueprint: Slide and Push Menus" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="sliding menu, pushing menu, navigation, responsive, menu, css, jquery" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="cbp-spmenu-push">
        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right beslagopties" id="beslagopties">
            <h3>Beslag</h3>

            <h2>Kies je beslag smaak:</h2>

            <input type="radio" name="smaakBeslag" value="Vanille" class="smaakBeslag"> Vanille<br>
            <input type="radio" name="smaakBeslag" value="Chocolade" class="smaakBeslag">Chocolade<br>
            <input type="radio" name="smaakBeslag" value="Aardbei" class="smaakBeslag"> Aardbei<br>
            <input type="radio" name="smaakBeslag" value="RedVelvet" class="smaakBeslag"> Red Velvet<br>
            <input type="radio" name="smaakBeslag" value="Banaan" class="smaakBeslag"> Banaan<br>
            <input type="radio" name="smaakBeslag" value="Kokos" class="smaakBeslag"> Kokos<br>

            <h2>Kies je beslagkleur:</h2>

            <button type="button" onclick="Function1()" >Blauw</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function2()" >Paars</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function3()" >Rood</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function4()" >Roze</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function5()" >Bruin</button><br/>

        </nav>

        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right bakingcupopties" id="bakingcupopties">
            <h3>BakingCup</h3>
            <h2>Kies je bakingcup kleur:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function6()" >Paars</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function7()" >Blauw</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function8()" >Geel</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function9()" >Rood</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function10()">Roze</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function11()">Wit</button><br/>

            <h2>Kies je bakingcup plaatje:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function12()" >Skulls</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function13()" >Hartjes</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function14()" >Bubbles</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function15()" >Bloemetjes</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function16()" >Niets</button><br/>
        </nav>

        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right plattetoppingding" id="plattetoppingding">
            <h3>Platte topping</h3>
            <h2> Kies je soort:</h2>
            <input type="radio" name="soortFondant" value="fondant" class="soortFondant">Fondant<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="soortFondant" value="marsepijn" class="soortFondant">Marsepijn<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="soortFondant" value="glazuur" class="soortFondant">Glazuur<br/>

            <h2> Kies je fondantkleur:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function17()" >Blauw</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function18()" >Bruin</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function19()" >Groen</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function20()" >Paars</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function21()" >Rood</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function22()" >Roze</button><br/>

            <h2> Kies je versiering:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function23()">Quilten</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function24()" >Lijnen</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function25()" >Rondjes</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function26()" >Geen</button>
        </nav>

        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right toeftopperding" id="toeftopperding">
            <h3>Toeftopping</h3>
            <h2>Kies je soort:</h2>
            <input type="radio" name="soortTopping" value="slagroom" class="soortTopping">Slagroom<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="soortTopping" value="botercreme" class="soortTopping">Botercreme<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="soortTopping" value="royal-icing" class="soortTopping">Royal Icing<br/>
            <input type="radio" name="soortTopping" value="creamcheese" class="soortTopping">Cream cheese<br/>

            <h2> Kies je toppingkleur:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function27()" >Paars</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function28()" >Blauw</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function29()" >Bruin</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function30()" >Geel</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function31()" >Oranje</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function32()" >Wit</button><br/>

            <h2>Kies je toppingversiering:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function33()" >Balletjes</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function34()" >Hagelslag</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function35()" >Discohagel</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function36()" >Geen</button><br/>
        </nav>

        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right topperding" id="topperding">
            <h3>Topper</h3>
            <h2> Kies je topper:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function37()" >Aardbei</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function38()" >Kers</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function39()" >Kaars</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function40()" >Hartje<</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function41()" >Bloemetje</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function42()" >Geen<br/></button>
        </nav>

        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right kaartjeding" id="kaartjeding">
            <h3>Kaartje</h3>
            <h2> Kies je kaartje:</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function43()" >Rood</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function44()" >Roze</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function45()" >Blauw</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function46()" >Geel</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function47()" >Groen</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function48()" >Wit</button><br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="Function49()" >Geen</button><br/>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <header class="clearfix">
                <span>Cupcakes...</span>
                <h1>Make your own!</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="main">
                <section>
                    <h2>Change it!</h2>
                    <!-- Class "cbp-spmenu-open" gets applied to menu -->

                    <button id="beslag1">Beslag</button>
                    <button id="bakingcup1">Baking cup</button>
                    <button id="plattetoppingding1">plat</button>
                    <button id="toeftopperding1">toef</button>
                    <button id="topperding1">topperding</button>
                    <button id="kaartjeding1">kaartjeding</button>
                    <!--<button id="plat1">Platte topping</button>
                    <button id="toef1">Toef topping</button>
                    <button id="topper1">Topper</button>
                    <button id="kaartje1">Kaartje</button>-->
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="images">
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Kleur/Schaduw-01.png"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Beslag/Rood-01.png" id="RoodBeslag"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Beslag/Blauw-01.png" id="BeslagBlauw"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Beslag/Paars-01.png" id="BeslagPaars"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Beslag/Roze-01.png" id="BeslagRoze"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Beslag/Bruin-01.png" id="BeslagBruin"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Kleur/Wit-01.png" id="BakjeWit"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Kleur/Roze-01.png" id="BakjeRoze"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Kleur/Rood-01.png" id="BakjeRood"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Kleur/Paars-01.png" id="BakjePaars"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Kleur/Geel-01.png" id="BakjeGeel"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Kleur/Blauw-01.png" id="BakjeBlauw"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Tekening/Hartjes-01.png" id="BakjeHartjes"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Tekening/skulls-01.png" id="BakjeSkulls"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Tekening/Bloemetjes-01.png" id="BakjeBloemetjes"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Bakje-Tekening/Bubbles-01.png" id="BakjeBubbles"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Kleur/Blauw-01.png" id="PlatBlauw"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Kleur/Bruin-01.png" id="PlatBruin"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Kleur/Groen-01.png" id="PlatGroen"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Kleur/Paars-01.png" id="PlatPaars"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Kleur/Rood-01.png" id="PlatRood"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Kleur/Roze-01.png" id="PlatRoze"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Versiering/Lijnen-01.png" id="PlatLijnen"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Versiering/Quilten-01.png" id="PlatQuilten"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Plat-Versiering/Rond-01.png" id="PlatRondjes"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Kleur/Blauw-01.png" id="ToefBlauw"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Kleur/Bruin-01.png" id="ToefBruin"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Kleur/Geel-01.png" id="ToefGeel"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Kleur/Oranje-01.png" id="ToefOranje"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Kleur/Paars-01.png" id="ToefPaars"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Kleur/Wit-01.png" id="ToefWit"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Versiering/Balletjes-01.png" id="ToefBalletjes"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Versiering/Discohagel-01.png" id="ToefDiscohagel"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toef-Versiering/Hagelslag-01.png" id="ToefHagelslag"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toppers/hartje-01.png" id="TopperHartje"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toppers/bloemetje-01.png" id="TopperBloemetje"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toppers/kers-01.png" id="TopperKers"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toppers/aardbei-01.png" id="TopperAardbei"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Toppers/kaars-01.png" id="TopperKaars"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Kaartje/blauw-01.png" id="KaartjeBlauw"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Kaartje/geel-01.png" id="KaartjeGeel"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Kaartje/groen-01.png" id="KaartjeGroen"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Kaartje/rood-01.png" id="KaartjeRood"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Kaartje/roze-01.png" id="KaartjeRoze"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/Kaartje/wit-01.png" id="KaartjeWit"/>
                <img src="../../Pictures/Cupcakeparts/transparant-01.png" id="Geen"/>
            </div>  
    </div>
        <!-- Classie - class helper functions by @desandro https://github.com/desandro/classie -->
        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
        <script>
            var 
                menuBeslag = document.getElementById( 'beslagopties' ),
                showBeslag = document.getElementById( 'beslag1' ),
                menuBakingcup = document.getElementById( 'bakingcupopties' ),
                showBakingcup = document.getElementById( 'bakingcup1' ),
                menuPlattetoppingding = document.getElementById( 'plattetoppingding' ),
                showPlattetoppingding = document.getElementById( 'plattetoppingding1' ),
                menuToeftopperding = document.getElementById( 'toeftopperding' ),
                showToeftopperding = document.getElementById( 'toeftopperding1' ),
                menuTopperding = document.getElementById( 'topperding' ),
                showTopperding = document.getElementById( 'topperding1' ),
                menuKaartjeding = document.getElementById( 'kaartjeding' ),
                showKaartjeding = document.getElementById( 'kaartjeding1' ),

                body = document.body;


            showBeslag.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuBeslag, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showBeslag' );
            };

            showBakingcup.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuBakingcup, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showBakingcup' ); 
            };

            showPlattetoppingding.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuPlattetoppingding, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showPlattetoppingding' ); 
            };

            showToeftopperding.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuToeftopperding, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showToeftopperding' ); 
            };

            showTopperding.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuTopperding, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showTopperding' ); 
            };

            showKaartjeding.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuKaartjeding, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showKaartjeding' ); 
            };



        function Function1() {
            x = document.getElementById('BeslagBlauw');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('Beslagpaars', 'RoodBeslag', 'BeslagRoze', 'BeslagBruin');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function2() {
            x = document.getElementById('BeslagPaars');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BeslagBlauw', 'RoodBeslag', 'BeslagRoze', 'BeslagBruin');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function3() {
            x = document.getElementById('RoodBeslag');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BeslagPaars', 'BeslagBlauw', 'BeslagRoze', 'BeslagBruin');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function4() {
            x = document.getElementById('BeslagRoze');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BeslagPaars', 'RoodBeslag', 'BeslagBlauw', 'BeslagBruin');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function5() {
            x = document.getElementById('BeslagBruin');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('Beslagpaars', 'RoodBeslag', 'BeslagRoze', 'BeslagBlauw');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function6() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjePaars');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeBlauw', 'BakjeGeel', 'BakjeRood', 'BakjeRoze', 'BakjeWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }


        function Function7() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeBlauw');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjePaars', 'BakjeGeel', 'BakjeRood', 'BakjeRoze', 'BakjeWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }


        function Function8() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeGeel');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeBlauw', 'BakjePaars', 'BakjeRood', 'BakjeRoze', 'BakjeWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function9() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeRood');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeBlauw', 'BakjeGeel', 'BakjePaars', 'BakjeRoze', 'BakjeWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }



function Function10() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeRoze');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeBlauw', 'BakjeGeel', 'BakjeRood', 'BakjePaars', 'BakjeWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function11() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeWit');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeBlauw', 'BakjeGeel', 'BakjeRood', 'BakjeRoze', 'BakjePaars');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function12() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeSkulls');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeHartjes', 'BakjeBloemetjes', 'BakjeBubbles');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function13() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeHartjes');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeSkulls', 'BakjeBloemetjes', 'BakjeBubbles');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function14() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeBubbles');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeHartjes', 'BakjeSkulls', 'BakjeBloemetjes');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function15() {
            x = document.getElementById('BakjeBloemetjes');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('BakjeHartjes', 'BakjeBubbles', 'BakjeSkulls');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function16() {
            x = document.getElementById('Geen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('Beslagpaars', 'RoodBeslag', 'BeslagRoze', 'BeslagBlauw');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }
        /*

        function Function17() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatBlauw');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById'PlatRood', 'PlatPaars', 'PlatGroen', 'PlatBruin', 'PlatRoze');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }


function Function18() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatBruin');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatRood', 'PlatPaars', 'PlatGroen', 'PlatBruin', 'PlatBlauw');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function19() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatGroen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatRood', 'PlatPaars', 'PlatRoze', 'PlatBruin', 'PlatBlauw');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function20() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatPaars');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatRood', 'PlatRoze', 'PlatGroen', 'PlatBruin', 'PlatBlauw');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function21() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatRood');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatRoze', 'PlatPaars', 'PlatGroen', 'PlatBruin', 'PlatBlauw');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function22() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatRoze');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatRood', 'PlatPaars', 'PlatGroen', 'PlatBruin', 'PlatBlauw');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function23() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatQuilten');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatLijnen','PlatRondjes');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function24() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatLijnen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatQuilten', 'PlatRondjes');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function25() {
            x = document.getElementById('PlatRondjes');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatLijnen', 'PlatQuilten');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function26() {
            x = document.getElementById('Geen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('PlatLijnen', 'PlatQuilten', 'PlatRondjes');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function27() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefPaars');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefOranje','ToefGeel','ToefBruin','ToefBlauw','ToefWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function28() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefBlauw');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefOranje','ToefGeel','ToefBruin','ToefWit','ToefPaars');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function29() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefBruin');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefOranje','ToefGeel','ToefWit','ToefBlauw','ToefPaars');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function30() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefGeel');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefOranje','ToefWit','ToefBruin','ToefBlauw','ToefPaars');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function31() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefOranje');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefWit','ToefGeel','ToefBruin','ToefBlauw','ToefPaars');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function32() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefWit');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefOranje','ToefGeel','ToefBruin','ToefBlauw','ToefPaars');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function33() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefBalletjes');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefDiscohagel','ToefHagelslag');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function34() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefHagelslag');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefDiscohagel', 'ToefBalletjes');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function35() {
            x = document.getElementById('ToefDiscohagel');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefHagelslag', 'ToefBalletjes');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function36() {
            x = document.getElementById('Geen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('ToefDiscohagel','ToefHagelslag', 'ToefBalletjes');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }


        function Function37() {
            x = document.getElementById('TopperAardbei');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('TopperBloemetje', 'TopperHartje', 'TopperKaars', 'TopperKers' );
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function38() {
            x = document.getElementById('TopperKers');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('TopperBloemetje', 'TopperHartje', 'TopperKaars', 'TopperAardbei' );
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function39() {
            x = document.getElementById('TopperKaars');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('TopperBloemetje', 'TopperHartje', 'TopperKers', 'TopperAardbei' );
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/  
        }

        function Function40() {
            x = document.getElementById('TopperHartje');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('TopperBloemetje', 'TopperKaars', 'TopperKers', 'TopperAardbei' );
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function41() {
            x = document.getElementById('TopperBloemetje');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('TopperHartje', 'TopperKaars', 'TopperKers', 'TopperAardbei' );
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/
        }

        function Function42() {
            x = document.getElementById('Geen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('TopperBloemetje', 'TopperHartje', 'TopperKaars', 'TopperKers', 'TopperAardbei' );
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function43() {
            x = document.getElementById('KaartjeRood');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /* = document.getElementById('KaartjeGroen', 'KaartjeGeel', 'KaartjeBlauw', 'KaartjeWit', 'KaartjeRoze');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function44() {
            x = document.getElementById('KaartjeRoze');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('KaartjeGroen', 'KaartjeGeel', 'KaartjeBlauw', 'KaartjeRood', 'KaartjeWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function45() {
            x = document.getElementById('KaartjeBlauw');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('KaartjeGroen', 'KaartjeGeel', 'KaartjeWit', 'KaartjeRood', 'KaartjeRoze');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function46() {
            x = document.getElementById('KaartjeGeel');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('KaartjeGroen', 'KaartjeWit', 'KaartjeBlauw', 'KaartjeRood', 'KaartjeRoze');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }
        function Function47() {
            x = document.getElementById('KaartjeGroen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('KaartjeWit', 'KaartjeGeel', 'KaartjeBlauw', 'KaartjeRood', 'KaartjeRoze');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }


        function Function48() {
            x = document.getElementById('KaartjeWit');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('KaartjeGroen', 'KaartjeGeel', 'KaartjeBlauw', 'KaartjeRood', 'KaartjeRoze');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/

        }

        function Function49() {
            x = document.getElementById('Geen');
            x.style.width=100%;
            /*y = document.getElementById('KaartjeGroen', 'KaartjeGeel', 'KaartjeBlauw', 'KaartjeRood', 'KaartjeRoze', 'KaartjeWit');
            y.style. opacity = 0;*/


        }

            /*function disableOther( button ) {

                if( button !== 'beslag1' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showBeslag, 'disabled' );
                }

                if( button !== 'bakingcup1' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showBakingcup, 'disabled' );
                }

                if( button !== 'plattetoppingding1' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showPlattetoppingding, 'disabled' );
                }

                if( button !== 'toeftopperding1' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showToeftopperding, 'disabled' );
                }


                if( button !== 'topperding1' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showTopperding, 'disabled' );
                }


                if( button !== 'kaartjeding1' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showKaartjeding, 'disabled' );
                }


            }*/
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code? Without it, not much we can do

Comment: Ehh.. how can I show it to you guys? I've got a lot of images linked in it?

Comment: Just paste the HTML in your original post. All we need is code, don't need to see what the images look like :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I am assuming there is some JavaScript involved. I noticed that was not one of your tags..

Comment: I like to use http://placecage.com/ when I want to add images to some HTML, just makes the internet happier :)

Comment: Is this a local version of your site? Or do you have a URL we could look at?

Comment: Hmmm... Now I got it kind of working... The only problem now is that when I clicked a button, the underlaying layers are still active. Any idea how I can make the earlier clicked links opacity 0 again? (so I won't have like 8 cupcake toppers overlapping eachother)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly speaking, you need the click to trigger some javascript code that changes the opacity of the relevant target.  A quickie example would be something like this:

```
<style>
.topping {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
<div onclick='changeOpacity()'>Click me</div>
<div id=changeme class=topping>Hello</div>
<script>

function changeOpacity() {
    x = document.getElementById('changeme');
    x.style.opacity = 1;
}
</script>
```

I think the relevant bit you're looking for is how to change the opacity (`x.style.opacity`, or you could use jQuery), but you'll also need to sort out how to link the buttons with the appropriate images.

And it might be a bit different with radio buttons, but it's essentially the same idea.

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked for a few moments... changed some things in my html and now it doesn't work anymore -,- added a new html file in my question tho.. can you take a look at it try to find out why iit doesn't work anymore? If I add the functions my sidebar doesn't work anymore... The functions and the sidebar actually worked for some time tonight... now it doesn't :x